# How to access model data using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, es6-modules

Since I have used first time node.js in es6 style. I am not able to fetch the data.

### UserModel.js :

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      username: { type: String, unique: true },
      password: String
});
var User = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema);
export default User;
```

### In Controller (custom style):

```
import User from '../schema/UserModel';
const UserCtrl = {};
UserCtrl.getUser =  (req, res) => {
      log(' In User Controller=========='); // ok
      try {
        const user = User.find({username: 'me'},(err, userDoc)=>{
          res.send(userDoc); 
        });
      }
      catch(err) {
        error('Error in getting user- ' + err); 
       // Error in getting user- TypeError: User.find is not a function
        res.status(400).send('not ok');
      } 
}
export default UserCtrl;

routes : app.get('/getUser', UserCtrl.getUser); // ok
```

mongoose: v5
express: v4

Please help me.

Comment: I have used 'babel-node'.

Comment: You're `await`ing a "callback". You cannot do that. Just `await the promise instead.

Comment: unfortunately, after removing also , it didn't made any difference.